# How to add Google Cloud (gcloud) to a Jenkins Helm chart

Tags: jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I want to incorporate the Google Cloud SDK (gcloud), PostgreSQL client (psql), and other tools into my Jenkins instance on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), which I'm installing using Helm from the official Jenkins Helm chart available at https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/jenkinsci/jenkins. What's the recommended approach for achieving this?"

Comment: I'd normally expect those tools to be built into the image you're deploying; you can't add individual tools to images at the Kubernetes or Helm level.